# Functional Lazily Instantiated Paths in Swift

Tags: swift, functional-programming, lazy-initialization

I would like a way to easily instantiate a "path" in Swift, or a sequence of Dictionaries.  For example, let's say that I have a class that's storing something like (slightly exaggerated):

```
class aClass<T: Hashable, U> {
  var paths:[T:[T:[T:[U]]]] = [:]
}
```

We have three separate `Dicts` that end in an `Array`.  I have some function that needs to store type `U` in the the array:

```
func store(path:(first:T,second:T,third:T), object:U)
```

How would you implement this without some kind nested pyramid of hell?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to set an empty `Dict` "dynamically" within the path if I access it and there's no `Dict` available.  Same with the the "leaf" array.

I guess what I'm hoping for is some kind of `infix` operator(s?) that would allow me to do something like this (assuming infix: `?>`, `>>`):

```
func store(path:(first:T,second:T,third:T), object:U) {
  paths[path.first] ?> [:] >> path.second ?> [:] >> path.third ?> []
  paths[path.first]?[path.second]?[path.third].append(object)
}
```

or, better yet:

```
func store(path:(first:T,second:T,third:T), object:U) {
  paths[path.first] ?> [:] >> path.second ?> [:] >> path.third ?> [] >>> { u in u.append(object) }
}
```

The problem I have is that both `Dict` and `Array` are passed by value in Swift.  This is forcing me into some serious nesting to get the "path" properly setup so I can insert a leaf object.

It's possible I'm asking too much of Swift, but as a semi-functional language, I keep thinking there's got to be an easier way to accomplish this.

## Update

I've come really, really close:

```
infix operator ?> { associativity left }
private func ?> <U,T>(var v:(d:[T:U], v:T), var r:U) -> U {
  if let dv = v.d[v.v] {
    return dv
  } else {
    v.d.updateValue(r, forKey: v.v)
    return r
  }
}

infix operator >< { associativity left }
private func >< <T,U>(t:T, u:U) -> (T,U) {
  return (t, u)
}

infix operator >>> { associativity left }
func >>> <T> (var v:T, f:(T -> ())) {
    f(v)
}
```

From here I should be able to do something like this:

```
paths >< path.first ?> [:] >< path.second ?> [:] >< path.third ?> [] >>> { arr in arr.append(object) }
```

This *almost* works.  The only error I get is:

> Immutable value of type '[T]' only has mutating members named 'append'

I can't seem to specify in the operator that I need the dictionary passed in to be mutable.  Any ideas?

I'll also admit that the `infix` operators do obscure the code a bit.  But even so, I posit that it's lot better than the 20+ lines of code required to maintain the nesting hell I would otherwise have to write.

### Update 2

It *doesn't* work.  It appears to work, but I've end up with the same problem I had previously:  The `Dict` and `Array` values are copied through the infix functions.  So with each "stage" of the transformation I'm modifying a copy instead of the original.  The problem is that there seems to be no way to pass a value by reference *out* of a function.  You can only pass a value by reference *in* to a function (using `inout`).